# In Sublime Text 3, find next match from current position and not from the beginning of the file

Tags: sublimetext3

If I enter a string to find in Sublime Text, it jumps to the first match in the file before I even press the Find button.

I would like it to
(1) jump to the next match from the current position, and 
(2) only after I pressed the Find button but not before.

Are there settings I could change to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this behaviour by turning off the `Highlight Matches` option in the find panel. In that case instead of showing you all of the matches as you search and jumping the cursor, Sublime waits for you to manually click `Find` or press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before it performs the search.

The button for this is the last one in the list of buttons in the `find` panel, to the left of the search term:

[image: Highlight Matches Button]

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! Easier than expected. I even saw the option but as it's called "Highlight Matches" I didn't think it would do what I intended to.

Comment: Frankly, to the Sublime Text designers -- don't you feel the description `Highlight Matches` is misleading? What does this behavior have to do with `"Highlight Matches"`? Shouldn't the description option be something like `Instant Search`?